# Delete protection for questions with a new answer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

#### Current situation

A questions cannot be deleted by their user if they have an upvoted/accepted answer or multiple answers.

The motivation with which I agree is that questions with good answers are valuable to the community.

#### Problem

However this leaves the following scenario open (which has happened to me):

An answer is written only for the question to be deleted within the next minute.

I think it should be fair for an answer be given a chance to get upvoted.

#### Proposed solution

So I suggest that to the list of conditions which prohibits one from deleting his/hers own question (see [When can’t I delete my own post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/254429)) to add the emphasized bullet:

> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - **has an answer with a score `0` or `-1` posted within the last `new_answer_protect_time`, or**
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

After `new_answer_protect_time` has elapsed if the answer hasn't accumulated a positive score (`>= 1`), the user can delete the question (given all other requirements still hold).

I propose `20 minutes` for `new_answer_protect_time`. One improvement I thought about is to make this time adaptable: longer for tags with low activity, shorter for tags with high activity.

#### Last words

This would be in the spirit of the current rules: **Good answers** and **the time invested** in writing them **are valuable** to the whole community.

Comment: I wouldn't mind to bring such questions to attention of those who can undelete stuff.

Comment: @pnuts I gues....

Comment: It is sensible but a very hard sell.  Time is entirely too tricky since it so greatly depends on the [tag] volume.  The view count is a much better measure but very hard to implement since it needs to start ticking from the moment the answer is posted and gets to be very hard to predict.  We do want the OP to delete an "oops, got that completely wrong" question.  Meanwhile, never hesitate to flag the question to ask for restoration, moderators rarely decline it.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much value to the community in preventing deletion of an otherwise bad question just because it recently received an answer. What if the answer is also horrible (which is often the case)? And I do not follow the logic in preventing posters from deleting their own question if the answer is also already at -1, no matter how new the answer is. If the only answer is already in negative territory *and* the OP thinks the question should be deleted, things are not trending in a good direction.

Comment: @EdCottrell one downvote in the first minutes isn't much representative. If the question doesn't reach `+1` in the time specified the op can delete the question.

Comment: @bolov true, but why should it prevent the OP from deleting the question?

Comment: @EdCottrell: A single downvote might be from the OP trying to circumvent this feature. If the answer hits -2, that means that at least one *other* user also thought it was bad.

Comment: [a user deleting answered question will be banned _very_ soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270539/165773)

Answer (score 4):

Obviously this is a behavior you'd like to prevent for the reasons you mention.  Who wants to spend time writing an answer, only to see the OP delete it quickly thereafter.

However, time based logic (especially for short-duration) can be a problem depending on the tag.  On popular tags, it won't be an issue, but on slow moving tags, it can be hours or days before someone qualified enough to judge the quality of the answer shows up to look at the question.  Similarly, we don't want to discourage the OP from cleaning up their own mess by blocking deletion only because they got answer.

I think the ideal solution is to just more eyes on the post to help evaluate and undelete it if necessary.  The simplest solution is a new section of the 10K moderator tools for "OP Deleted posts with answers".  It would give 10K users the ability to see such posts and cast an undelete vote as necessary.

Comment: the time based logic was something thrown on the side, not the main focus. I agree with not discouraging the OP from cleaning up their own mess.

Comment: Do people actually still actively monitor (or even know about) that old 10k tools page? I know it took me a while to realize what you were talking about. A new review queue (10k+ only, obviously) might be better. Or just make it raise an automatic mod flag, if it doesn't happen often enough to merit an actual review queue.