# Request for moderation: New user asked and deleted own questions including good answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

Following the suggestion posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/request-to-undelete-a-question#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%20request%20that,the%20question%20will%20be%20undeleted.), I'd like feedback on a situation I encountered yesterday from a new user. The new user posted around 5 questions, each seemingly building a bit off the others. Several questions had lots of activity (comments and answers), including [one useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471030/linux-how-to-convert-task-list-to-list-head/67472154#67472154) that I posted. I then noticed that the user deleted most of their questions, but kept posting new ones. I ended up asking the user on a new question why they were deleting their own questions and they claimed they wanted to [rewrite the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67476917/linux-kernel-should-i-use-asmlinkage-for-a-function-that-implements-a-system-cal). This on top of asking and deleting questions from an alternate account (I know this because the user [asked for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463187/linux-how-to-check-if-list-head-is-empty?noredirect=1#comment119255924_67463187) on a question by another user that is also [now deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462685/kernel-pointer-to-current-process?noredirect=1#comment119242035_67462685), but I think had overlapping code).

TLDR:

1. I felt that [the answer and discussion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471030/linux-how-to-convert-task-list-to-list-head/67472154#67472154) me and another SO user provided were useful for the community as well as something I'd like to reference in the future myself. I don't have the reputation to vote to undelete, but if any mods agree with my sentiment, I would appreciate undeleting the question.
2. I would love feedback/discussion on whether there's anything to be done about this strange behavior. One idea I have is as soon as there is an answer on a question, the OP can only vote to delete the question instead of the automatic delete.

Comment: Related [What to do when a question you answered gets deleted intentionally?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316117/11682469) Note that technically, the OP already just votes to delete but when there's only one answer without upvotes, the system allows them to delete their question.

Comment: They are (presumably) heavily penalized in the q-ban algorithm, though.

Comment: *"I would love feedback/discussion on whether there's anything to be done about this strange behavior. "* Users with 10K rep can vote to undelete the question. Other than that, if the user keeps deleting things like that then (like mentioned) the ban algorithm may well act accordingly (we don't know what the algorithm is, so impossible to say with conviction).

Comment: @JeanneDark maybe I should have changed my feature request/discussion then to "as soon as there is an answer on a question the post needs two votes to delete instead of just one (the OP)".

Comment: @Larnu What reasons do 10k users find worthy enough of undeleting posts? Should I have included topic/tag in the post so that the top users from the tag can assess for themselves the value of the question I'm asking to reopen?

Comment: [Asker can delete question as soon as an answer is received, which also deletes answer. Design/flaw?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289338/11682469) [Delete protection for questions with a new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310206/11682469) [Only allow questions to be deleted if a downvoted answer or no answer is present](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261666/11682469)

Comment: @wxz - I typically vote to undelete a question when it can actually be answered.  If I find a contributor removing contributions because of a single downvote i typical notify a moderator.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm not able to see vote counts yet, do you know if the OP in the linked questions deleted because of downvotes? Like I said, I felt that the question they posted had a clear answer (which I provided). At the end, they started modifying their own code which makes it a little less obvious what the original question was. Maybe that's why no one here has offered to reopen? Perhaps reopen and rollback to original question is the better request?

Comment: I wonder how we could better convey to new users that editing is *the* way to "rewrite their questions"/ adjust wording, and that deletion is something that they should very rarely need to do. Clearly that messaging is lost on or never makes it to a lot of folks.

Comment: @zcoop98 In addition to what I've suggested, what if clicking the delete button on your own post brings up a pop-up saying that editing is preferred over deleting and that deleting should only be used in xy scenarios? Similar to the new queue pop-up that happens when you view the queues for the first time.

Comment: @zcoop98 It's such a tricky balance because we also don't want a scenario where new users then think that editing their question progressively as their programming problems change is the way to go (i.e. losing the meaning of the original question). To some extent, the OP this post is about started doing that on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471030/linux-how-to-convert-task-list-to-list-head/67472154#67472154), asking for confirmation of the new code they edited in, instead of accepting an answer and creating another question for the new obstacles they faced.

Comment: @wxz - It was either deleted by the community or the author of the question.  If there wasn't a single downvote that is even worse.

Comment: The [banner at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxmdc.png) of the post indicates that the question author deleted it themselves.

Comment: @SecurityHound Yeah it was the author and I imagine no down votes based on their “rewrite” justification. Arghh.

Comment: We could add another review queue (self-deleted questions with answers) or have a minimal waiting time for self deletions.

Comment: @Trilarion I like the idea of a review queue, except I'd be concerned that the natural tendency of reviewers would be to delete indiscriminately (with the goal of "cleaning up" SO). Minimal wait time for self-deletions would also be good.

Comment: @Trilarion In theory that could work, but in practice: We already have enough full queues, adding a new one will help probably no one

Answer (score 25):

There's a bit more to this under the surface. Users that fit this pattern

- Joined the network recently
- Overly simplistic user name
- Are posting lots of academic type questions
- Delete soon after getting an answer

are often times students asking questions [they know will get them in trouble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/ive-rethought-my-question-about-a-homework-assignment-why-cant-i-get-it-delete). Based on [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67462993/2370483), it's probably the case (they claim it's a "job interview question" but I don't buy it).

---

In all cases, if you see a user delete a question with a valid answer mere minutes after getting said answer, mod flag it. If you see a user chain-posting (or a user reposting what another user posted), mod flag it.

Comment: That's what I started to think too. I ended up flagging a different question they posted because I couldn't find the deleted question, since I didn't have the rep. Then I realized it still showed up in my "recently deleted answers", hence why I could link it on this post.

Answer (score 15):

The root of the issue is that the asker has an XY problem (which you yourself noticed on their first question), but isn't willing to elucidate the Y, so they ended up asking multiple disparate questions instead of a single coherent one. To make matters worse, they then deleted the previous questions in the "chain" **and** edited their most recent one to reflect your answer.

I think a moderator should reach out to this user and inform them that their behaviour is likely to lead to a question ban (if it hasn't already), plus encourage them to write a full Y question that you can properly answer.

If that doesn't happen, my suggestion would be for you to write your own question that links the disparate bits together, something like "How do I write a syscall that sums the PIDs of children processes recursively?", and then **self-answer** it with a combination of the good answers you've already posted to this user's other questions.

That way, if the user's questions do get deleted for whatever reason in the future, at least your good question and answer will remain.

Comment: Totally agree with your assessment of where OP went wrong. Funny enough, I diverge in thinking when it comes to the issue with the XY problem, I agree with this statement from the XY problem [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/949652): "You're not supposed to post both X and Y in the same question thread, and the X question alone without Y shows that the questioner wants somebody else to do his work for him." I thought the Y questions from OP were the useful ones and if the OP had only posted X, I probably would have flagged for asking us to solve a programming project for them.

Comment: To me the XY issue was having the title be the Y question, and then in the post getting sidetracked with throwing in the X problem too. Another thought I've had is that the rapidity of the OPs questions (at least 5 in 24 hours) might indicate OP was intentionally chopping up their X problem into Y problems so that we wouldn't complain about being asked to do their work, but collectively would still get the job done for them. That's the cynical part of me though.